# Using awk to search for lines that have a number of digits

Tags: awk

Here is file1

```
200
201
202
203
204
205
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
```

Is there an awk oneliner that finds only lines with three digits in the the first field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we can assume that the first field only contains numbers:

```
awk 'length($1) == 3' file1
```

If not, go with one of the regex solutions.

---

An alternative solution:

```
awk '$1 >= 100 && $1 <= 999' file1
```

print all line where the numeric value of the first field is in the range (100,999).
This solution has two caveats:

1. `100aap` gets converted to `100`, and gets printed.
2. `005` gets converted to `5`, and doesn't get printed.

Comment: About 1,000 times more readable than all the regexp solutions (including mine)

Answer (score 23):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' file1
```

This will match the first field (`$1`) against three digits only (note the forced start and stop range denoted by `^` and `$`). It then prints the entire line (`$0`). You don't need a `{print $0}` after the regex match, because the default action is to print the line anyway.

If you want to use the **interval expression** operator `{}` in your regex then you will need to use `gawk` and the `--posix` switch:

```
gawk --posix '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{3}$/' file1
```

Comment: `{}` ranges don't require gawk, just a POSIX compliant awk. You don't need the `--posix` flag when using with gawk.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber `{}` ranges are enabled by default since gawk 4.0. In earlier versions you need to pass `-W re-interval` or `-W posix` (or GNU long options equivalents) to enable it.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{3}$/' file1
```

Or, if you prefer a range instead of the POSIX character class:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{3}$/' file1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]([^0-9]|$)/ {print $0}' file
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/MFmQN)

To find lines that have only 3 digits and nothing else:

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ {print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit unorthodox but you can do this as well -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text7
200
201
202
203
204
205
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="";} NF<4{print}' text7
200
201
202
203
204
205
```

Comment: Unorthodox and unportable. According to POSIX: "If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified". And it doesn't work when the input contains more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/) print $0}' file
```

Note that we're using a reg-ex that specifies 3 char-classes (anything inside `[..]`), of *just* 0-9. The first field of a file is denoted as $1. The '^' and '$', indicate start and end of field. If we don't have those there, fields with 4 or more digits will also match.

I hope this helps.

Comment: should probably be awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/) print $0}' or it matches all lines that have at least 3 digits, should't it? (assuming the OP wants EXACTLY three digits)

Comment: Yes, I was testing/editing and added that. Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{num=$1/1; if (num == $1) if (length($1) == 3) print $0}' file
```

Should work with leading zero(s)